# Raster names are different from filenames when "stacking" rasters using terra

Tags: r, spatial, terra

I've created a list with raster filenames from a folder, then want to import those rasters into R in a "stack" using {terra}, and eventually am wanting to use {terra} to extract values from those rasters at points in a shapefile. My raster files are all uniquely named in my file folder; however, in some cases I have rasters that are named similarly (e.g., `canflax2017.tif`, `canflax2018.tif`, `canflax2019.tif`, `canflax2018_137.tif`, `canflax2018_51.tif`, `canflax2017_137.tif`, etc). When I get all the rasters in a "stack" it seems to cut off the year in the resulting raster name, but only for the filenames without a `"_"` in the raster name. For example, `canflax2017`, `canflax2018`, `canflax2019` all have the name `canflax` and aren't unique, but `canflax2018_137`, `canflax2018_51`, and `canflax2019_137` are fine and show the whole filename. Of course, then when I want to extract values from the stack, the columns for `canflax2017`, `canflax2018`, `canflax2019` are just named `canflax`, `canflax.1`, `canflax.2`  etc. in the output dataframe. Any thoughts to ensure that the whole filename somehow gets incoporated into the stack information?

Code below:

```r
library(terra)

rastsfilelist<-list.files(path="XXX/AllRasters",pattern="tif$",full.names = TRUE)
owl_stack<-rast(rastsfilelist)

owllocs <- vect('XX/shapefiletest.shp')
test<-extract(owl_stack,owllocs)
```

Here's the information regarding names for each raster in the stack
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5STs3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make sure, the layer names in different rasters (files) have different names. An example below: layer names are the same regardless of file names until I change them.

```r
l <- list.files(path = "/home/sapi/projekty/test", pattern = "above", full.names = TRUE)
l
#> [1] "/home/sapi/projekty/test/above_a.tif"
#> [2] "/home/sapi/projekty/test/above_b.tif"
#> [3] "/home/sapi/projekty/test/above_c.tif"
r <- terra::rast(l)
r
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 25, 22, 3  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 8.181818, 7.2  (x, y)
#> extent      : 0, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
#> sources     : above_a.tif  
#>               above_b.tif  
#>               above_c.tif  
#> names       : lyr.1, lyr.1, lyr.1 
#> min values  :    10,    10,    10 
#> max values  :    10,    10,    10
w <- terra::rast("/home/sapi/projekty/test/above_a.tif")
names(w) <- "other_name"
w
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 25, 22, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 8.181818, 7.2  (x, y)
#> extent      : 0, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
#> source      : above_a.tif 
#> name        : other_name 
#> min value   :         10 
#> max value   :         10
terra::writeRaster(w, filename = "/home/sapi/projekty/test/above_d.tif", overwrite = TRUE)
l <- list.files(path = "/home/sapi/projekty/test", pattern = "above", full.names = TRUE)
x <- terra::rast(l)
x
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 25, 22, 4  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 8.181818, 7.2  (x, y)
#> extent      : 0, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
#> sources     : above_a.tif  
#>               above_b.tif  
#>               above_c.tif  
#>               above_d.tif  
#> names       : lyr.1, lyr.1, lyr.1, other_name 
#> min values  :    10,    10,    10,         10 
#> max values  :    10,    10,    10,         10
```

To change names you can use `setNames()` function like:

```r
l[[1]] |>
  terra::rast() |>
  setNames(basename(l[[1]]))

#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 25, 22, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 8.181818, 7.2  (x, y)
#> extent      : 0, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
#> source      : above_a.tif 
#> name        : above_a.tif 
#> min value   :          10 
#> max value   :          10
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-22 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks Grzegorz! I ended up pulling the names from the filelist and then assigning those names to the stack and it seems to work fine now:
rastnames<-tools::file_path_sans_ext(rastsfilelist<list.files(path="XXX/AllRasters",pattern="tif$"))

names(owl_stack)<-rastnames

I still can't figure out how terra assigns the names to the rasters in the stack though - it seemed extremely random. I even changed some filenames in my folder and sometimes terra seemed to import the original filename as the raster name